# How can I make Android Studio run the app on the phone plugged into the local computer over a remote connection?

Tags: windows-10, networking, remote-desktop, android-studio

I am remoting into another PC on my home network and want to be able to run my app on the phone that I plug into my laptop. How can I accomplish this? I've already tried sharing the drives via the RDP settings but this didn't work.

PC/Android Studio -> RDP -> laptop -> phone

Comment: I would wonder if this could be done. To the best of my knowledge, running an app on a physical devices requires either a direct USB or Bluetooth connection. Fooling Android Studio into thinking a phone is physically connected to the PC when it isn't seems like it may not be possible.

Comment: @Anaksunaman that makes me sad :(